# How to delete and update database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, datatable, ado

I have a Table in Sql server, my app has a form, which uses DataSet to fill the fields in. This has been working fine, but I wanted to sort the DataTable by model number, so used a DataTable to sort the view. Now Add New works fine, but update adds a new row and delete doesn't. Some guidance please?

I've tried:

```
DataRow row = GlobalClass.ds.Tables[0].Rows[inc];
row[0] = tbModelNo.Text + "-" + tbRevision.Text;  
objConnect.UpdateDatabase(GlobalClass.ds); 
row.AcceptChanges();
```

which doesn't update nor adds a new row

```
GlobalClass.ds.Tables[0].Rows[inc].Delete();
GlobalClass.ds.AcceptChanges();
objConnect.UpdateDatabase(GlobalClass.ds);
```

which doesn't delete

```
// save new, works ok

DataRow row = GlobalClass.ds.Tables[0].NewRow();    
row[0] = tbModelNo.Text + "-" + tbRevision.Text;
GlobalClass.ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
objConnect.UpdateDatabase(GlobalClass.ds);

// delete doesn’t work

GlobalClass.ds.Tables[0].Rows[inc].Delete();
objConnect.UpdateDatabase(GlobalClass.ds);

// update, adds a new row not updates

DataRow row = GlobalClass.ds.Tables[0].Rows[inc];
row[0] = tbModelNo.Text + "-" + tbRevision.Text;  
objConnect.UpdateDatabase(GlobalClass.ds);
```

I expect delete row to delete like it did before using DataTable to sort by model no, and update to simply change the row not add a new one.

Comment: What does your UpdateDatabase method do?

Comment: Also show your attempt to use AcceptChanges, together with any error details.

Comment: @AndyG It's a method from DatabaseConnection, objConnect = new DatabaseConnection();

Comment: @AndyG         public void UpdateDatabase(System.Data.DataSet ds)
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb = new 
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(da_1);

            cb.DataAdapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);

        }